# Node.js install jingo wiki

Tags: node.js

I would like to instal the [jingo wiki](https://github.com/claudioc/jingo) on my uberspace webspace. i tried to follow the tutorials here

https://github.com/claudioc/jingo and https://wiki.uberspace.de/development:nodejs (german)

but I'am still totally overcharged because I don't have any experiences with node.js.

I cloned jingo to a folder ~/jingo. Then I changed my node.js to version 7

```
$ echo 'export PATH=/package/host/localhost/nodejs-7/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

I then did `npm install` inside the jingo folder and get some warnings:

```
npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated transformers@2.1.0: Deprecated, use jstransformer
```

I also did

```
$ test -d ~/service || uberspace-setup-svscan
```

to start node.js as service (as far as I understood).

Then following the Uberspace tutorial, I should do

```
$ uberspace-setup-service exampleservice node ~/example.js
```

to start the application. But I actually don't know, where to find the `*.js` file in jingo to start it. How can I go forward?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I solved it somehow. First you have to set up the config.yaml (as described here: https://github.com/claudioc/jingo) and then start the wiki with the executable jingo in the source folder like:

```
jingo -c /path/to/config.yaml
```

or as service on uberspace

```
uberspace-setup-service jingo node "~/jingo/jingo -c /path/to/config.yaml"
```

Then you have to build a redirect to localhost:67102 (or whatever jingo is listening on, you can set it in the config.yaml)

Its still not working very well, because I get an 44 error and the styles are also 404, but at least you can see that the wiki is started.